# Angular2 - Reference template reference variable declared in child element

Tags: angular

Using Angular2 API, is it possible to reference a template reference variable declared in child element from a parent element?

```
<div [class]="el.valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error'">
  <input [(ngModel)]="setting.value" required #el="ngModel">
</div>
```

Also a slightly different question: is it possible to reference the validity of a child form element from a parent element?

I should add that I'm only looking for a way to do it in HTML using Angular2 API without having to reference it in the component.

Comment: Have you tried using @ViewChild? If not, you can always use a service to pass around info.

Comment: Looking for more direct and declarative way to do it.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`exportAs` property](https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26#.s2166j54t)?